# Putting 4 TDs in a TR but aligning 2 TDs one line

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a table where I insert 2 tds in each tr.
In this table there is a scenario where I insert 4 tds in the tr. 
I want the 4 tds in the tr to be aligned as "2 tds in one line".

[image: Table example]

a-h are html elements. Elements e, f, g, h are connected and I want to insert these elements in one cell so as not to show the border lines.

```
<table>
 <tr>

  <td>work</td>
  <td >

   <select id="work" name="work">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
 </td>

<td>Others:</td>
<td >                       
  <input id="insert_loc" maxlength="96" name="other_loc"    style="width:180px" type="text" />
</td>
```

How can I go about achieving this?
Thanks.

**EDIT:
I guess I was overthinking it. As Scott suggested showing/hiding borders using CSS is the way to go. 
For anyone interested:**

```
td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code we can work with?

Comment: @RadicalFanatic: The table is generated dynamically. I can give a sample code. Check my edited question.

Comment: Looks to me as though you merely need differing classes to show/hide cell borders, that's all.

Comment: @Scott: It's true that the the table uses some css for design. How can I hide the borders? Would including `style="border 0px;"` in the td elements do? I tried it but no effect.